# Incompatibility between fixltx2e, subfigure and figure*

Tags: floats, subfloats, incompatibility

This minimal example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
asdf
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

gives the error:

```
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. [\end{figure*}]
```

when compiling with pdflatex.  Is this a bug?  Can this be fixed without changing packages?  I'm aware that subfigure is deprecated.

Comment: Being aware that `subfigure` is deprecated, you can use [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption). It provides similar functionality and is compatible.

Comment: @Werner I'm using a third-party class which is incompatible with subcaption.

Comment: With `subfig`, the successor of `subfigure`, it runs without any error. BTW: It did not matter for the example, but in general you should load `fixltx2e` straight after the document class.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it could be solved with replacing an obsolete with an up-to-date package.

Comment: @Speravir I'm using `subfigure` because it provides `subtable`, which `subcaption` and `subfig` do not.  I'm sure there are ways to avoid `subtable`, but that's a separate question.

Comment: Can you share the class?  It might be a simple fix to get `subcaption` (which does include a 'subtable' environment) up and running.  And since `subfigure` is deprecated and `fixltx2e` is *rarely* updated, your best bet might be to switch.

Comment: yes they do provide subtable. you can safely drop the usage of subfigure. there is nothing that it can and others can't do.

Comment: @1'': You mention prerequisites in comments, you _should_ have mentioned in your question! Either make a remarkable edit and hope, that this question is reopened, or ask a new one, where you consider comments of other people here (with the risk, that this is closed, too).

Comment: @Speravir The question, as edited, is fairly clear.  Mainly I'm asking for my own knowledge; also, if there is an incompatibility, even in a deprecated package, it should be known to the community.  In my case, I solved the problem before asking the question, by removing fixltx2e.